# Overlay control over 2 dockable panels of AvalonDock

Tags: wpf, vb.net, avalondock

I am creating an interface using WPF which contains a menu of tiles. UI has an image which is below the menubar. When the menu bar is hidden the image expands and takes its place as I am using Avalon Dock.
I have a design in which, menu tiles expand in height when mouse is hovered over them. But the expanded tiles get hidden as the dockable panel doesn't expand in height. Is there a way to overlay the tiles' panel over the image panel so that the tiles are visible entirely?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot over the internet and also documentations. Finally found out that, the 2 panels are separate components so content among it can't be overlayed.
eg. a button can't be shared by 2 windows as their Visual Tree is different.

So, the answer to my Question is that the components can't be overlayed.